# Ignoring empty cells in Google app scripts function

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I wrote this function to bring spreadsheet entries into my calendar. As you see, now I take all entries in the range B5:B30. If I do not fill in all cells in this range, I get an error as my parameters are wrong.

Now if I would be able to only take the values from this range that are not empty, I think all would work. Is there a way to drop empty cells from my range or only execute `getValue()` and save it in my definition of signups if there is a value?

```
function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow()

var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B5:D30").getValues()

for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
var shift = signups[x];
var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];
var volunteer= shift[2];
eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  if (volunteer && startTime && endTime) {
    eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
  }
```

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This worked:

```
function scheduleShifts() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow()

var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B5:D30").getValues()

for (x=0; x<signups.length;x++)
{
var shift = signups[x];
var startTime = shift[0];
var endTime = shift[1];
var volunteer= shift[2];
if (volunteer && startTime && endTime){
eventCal.createEvent(volunteer, startTime, endTime);
}
}}
```